# iPhone OpenGL fps test

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl, testing, frame-rate

Anyone can tell me how to get and display the fps (frame rate) of a running program on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XCode, Run -> Start with Performance Tool -> OpenGL ES

That launches instruments with GL tool, where you'll see FPS
and GPU utilization. If you're not achieving your lickable 60fps
then GPU % is the number you'll need to lower.

Comment: is there anyway i could print out the value of the fps on screen instead? the performance tool wouldn't work on the actual real iphone...

Comment: Sure, you can count the number of times per second that you're calling  presentRenderbuffer and print that number on the screen.